# Reading Code From a Text File Efficiently And How to Distinguish Blocks of Code In The Text File

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a utility for a game that creates spreadsheets of data by reading the game's code.

One of the most basic aspects of this is being able to read the game's code efficiently. The game is written in C#. I'm using VB.Net for my program because my mind can't grasp the abstraction of more complex languages. Historically the way I had my program recognise code blocks in the code text file is by counting the brackets that encapsulated them and working off of that. This seems a bit clunky, though. Is there any simpler way to help the program figure out code blocks?

For Example, code in the text file might look like this:

```
6673={
    key="d_example_duchy_1"
    de_facto_liege=12
    variables={
        data={ {
                flag="traditional_de_jure_kingdom"
                tick=0
                data={
                    type=lt
                    identity=6632
                }
            }
 }
    }
    de_jure_liege=6632
    de_jure_vassals={ 6674 6678 6682 6686 }
    holder=558
    name="Example Duchy 1"
    date=1253.1.1
    heir={ 880 }
    history={ 1253.1.1=558 }
    capital=6674
    history_government="tribal_government"
    coat_of_arms_id=2320
}
6674={
    key="c_example_county_1"
    variables={
        data={ {
                flag="influx_culture"
                tick=0
                data={
                    type=culture
                    identity=11
                }
            }
 {
                flag="influx_faith"
                tick=0
                data={
                    type=faith
                    identity=57
                }
            }
 {
                flag="fog_resistance"
                tick=0
                data={
                    type=value
                }
            }
 }
    }
    de_jure_liege=6673
    de_jure_vassals={ 6675 6676 6677 }
    holder=558
    name="Example County 1"
    date=1243.6.26
    heir={ 880 }
    capital=6674
    coat_of_arms_id=2323
}
6675={
    key="b_example_barony_1"
    de_facto_liege=6674
    de_jure_liege=6674
    holder=558
    name="Example Barony 1"
    date=1254.1.1
    capital_barony=yes
    duchy_capital_barony=yes
    capital=6674
    coat_of_arms_id=2328
}
6676={
    key="b_example_barony_2"
    de_facto_liege=6674
    de_jure_liege=6674
    holder=11609
    name="Example Barony 2"
    date=1253.7.28
    capital=6674
    coat_of_arms_id=2332
}
6677={
    key="b_example_barony_3"
    de_facto_liege=6674
    de_jure_liege=6674
    holder=558
    name="Example Barony 3"
    date=1232.2.8
    heir={ 880 }
    capital=6674
    theocratic_lease=yes
    coat_of_arms_id=2334
}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Really hard question to answer.  Is their a cleaner way, quite possible.  Do you have any control over what is generating these files?  Could you possible rejig that to tag things?  It looks like json so could you deserialize it into collections of objects that you can inspect properties of?

Comment: How are you getting access to the source code?

Comment: @Hursey I don't have any control over what is generating these files, but the code of the base game files is C# based so I assumed this (which is a save file) is also C#.

Comment: @Mary A lot of the code is open because the game supports modding extensively. This code in particular is from decompressing a save file.

Comment: @Hursey
Would doing File.ReadAllText into a single string and then parsing it by looking at both code brackets and carriage returns work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I eventually settled on, for discerning the overall code-blocks (e.g. all the data nested under `6674={ ... }`) was basically:

```
Dim Code As String = File.ReadAllText("PATH/TO/CODE/FILE.txt")
Dim Output As List(Of String) = Code.Split(vbCrLf & "}" & vbCrLf).ToList
```

So in plain English, reading all the code into a single string, then splitting the string according to how the original code's language distinguished the *initial* nest of code (i.e. a carriage return followed by a curly bracket followed by another carriage return).

The list at the end would look something like this:

Output(0)

```
6673={" & vbCrLf & "    key=""d_example_duchy_1""" & vbCrLf & "    de_facto_liege=12" & vbCrLf & "    variables={" & vbCrLf & "        data={ {" & vbCrLf & "                flag=""traditional_de_jure_kingdom""" & vbCrLf & "                tick=0" & vbCrLf & "                data={" & vbCrLf & "                    type=lt" & vbCrLf & "                    identity=6632" & vbCrLf & "                }" & vbCrLf & "            }" & vbCrLf & " }" & vbCrLf & "    }" & vbCrLf & "    de_jure_liege=6632" & vbCrLf & "    de_jure_vassals={ 6674 6678 6682 6686 }" & vbCrLf & "    holder=558" & vbCrLf & "    name=""Example Duchy 1""" & vbCrLf & "    date=1253.1.1" & vbCrLf & "    heir={ 880 }" & vbCrLf & "    history={ 1253.1.1=558 }" & vbCrLf & "    capital=6674" & vbCrLf & "    history_government=""tribal_government""" & vbCrLf & "    coat_of_arms_id=2320
```

Output(1)

```
6674={" & vbCrLf & "    key=""c_example_county_1""" & vbCrLf & "    variables={" & vbCrLf & "        data={ {" & vbCrLf & "                flag=""influx_culture""" & vbCrLf & "                tick=0" & vbCrLf & "                data={" & vbCrLf & "                    type=culture" & vbCrLf & "                    identity=11" & vbCrLf & "                }" & vbCrLf & "            }" & vbCrLf & " {" & vbCrLf & "                flag=""influx_faith""" & vbCrLf & "                tick=0" & vbCrLf & "                data={" & vbCrLf & "                    type=faith" & vbCrLf & "                    identity=57" & vbCrLf & "                }" & vbCrLf & "            }" & vbCrLf & " {" & vbCrLf & "                flag=""fog_resistance""" & vbCrLf & "                tick=0" & vbCrLf & "                data={" & vbCrLf & "                    type=value" & vbCrLf & "                }" & vbCrLf & "            }" & vbCrLf & " }" & vbCrLf & "    }" & vbCrLf & "    de_jure_liege=6673" & vbCrLf & "    de_jure_vassals={ 6675 6676 6677 }" & vbCrLf & "    holder=558" & vbCrLf & "    name=""Example County 1""" & vbCrLf & "    date=1243.6.26" & vbCrLf & "    heir={ 880 }" & vbCrLf & "    capital=6674" & vbCrLf & "    coat_of_arms_id=2323
```

And so on with the remaining three.